# KDE apps fonts show as square signs

Tags: 18.04, kde, fonts

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and it works fine but all the KDE apps dialogs look like this to me, any idea what is wrong?

[image: broken dialog fonts]

Comment: Do you get any hints if you open KDE applications in a terminal?